# GetOrdersRequestType isn't returning MonetaryDetails with ReturnAll

Tags: java, ebay-api

I'm trying to access the Monetary Details return of the GetOrders api call in order to return the paypal transaction ID. I've understand I need to have the request Return All to access this required information so I have added that to my request:

```
GetOrdersRequestType request = new GetOrdersRequestType();

DetailLevelCodeType[] detailLevels = new DetailLevelCodeType[]{ DetailLevelCodeType.RETURN_ALL };    

request.setDetailLevel(detailLevels);
request.setCreateTimeFrom(fromDate);
request.setCreateTimeTo(toDate);
request.setOrderRole(TradingRoleCodeType.SELLER);
request.setOrderStatus(OrderStatusCodeType.COMPLETED);
request.setPagination(paginationType);
```

Adding this though will not return Monetary Detail and ExternalTransaction as null.

I'm using api version 849.

Any ideas would be most welcome.